# What does need to be considered for getting a non-trivial eigenspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, solution-verification

Compute  the  non-trivial  eigenspaces  of $T∈ L(\mathbb{R}^2)$  where $T$ is  defined  by, $T(x,y) = (x+y,−y)$.

My solution (without knowing what exactly is the non-trivial eigenspace):

Consider for $v=(x,y)$ s.t $Tv= \lambda v$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, where $v \neq 0$ ($v \neq 0$ is what I think that make an eigenspace non-trivial because I think a trivial eigenspace is $\{ 0 \}.)$

$$Tv=(x+y,-y)= \lambda (x,y)$$
$$\Rightarrow \lambda=-1$$
$$\Rightarrow -x=x+y$$
$$\Rightarrow y=-2x$$

Thus, a non-trivial eigenspace is $E(-1,T)= \operatorname{span}((1,-2))$.

Is the method right? And, is my understanding of a non-trivial eigenspace correct?

Comment: Yes, the eigenspace is nontrivial if it contains a vector $v\ne 0$. Your calculation is also roughly where it should be. What is wrong in it was to conclude from $-y=\lambda y$ that $\lambda=-1$. What about the case $y=0$? (Work out that case, and it will give you *another* eigenspace spanned by $(1,0)$ for eigenvalue $1$.)

Comment: @StinkingBishop Oh, I missed that case. Thank you, so will the answer be "span(1,0) and span(1,2)"?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Isn´t it $E_{-1}(T)=span (\begin{pmatrix}1\\-2\end{pmatrix})$?

Comment: @PeterMelech Yes, you are right! There was another mistake. Thank you!

Comment: The mistake was $-x=x+y\implies y=2x$, it should be $-x=x+y\implies y=-2x$

Comment: You´re welcome!